# need count of how many files are in folder, mysql tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
documents: id, folder_id

folders: id, title
```

I want to retrieve a list of folders and count of how many files relate to that folder (documents.folder_id = folders.id)

I tried this

```
select 
 f.title, count(d.id) as file_count
from
 folders f
left join
 documents d on f.id = d.folder_id
```

But that only returns one row, with the total number of rows in the documents table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `GROUP BY` clause to return a row per `f.title`.

```
select 
 f.title, count(d.id) as file_count
from
 folders f
left join
 documents d on f.id = d.folder_id
GROUP BY f.title
```

Note that the above will omit empty folders, I believe. If you want a zero count for the empty folders, use `COUNT(d.*)` instead:

```
select 
 f.title, count(d.*) as file_count
from
 folders f
left join
 documents d on f.id = d.folder_id
GROUP BY f.title
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT F.id, F.title, COUNT(D.*)
FROM folders AS F
     LEFT OUTER JOIN documents AS D ON D.folder_id = F.id
GROUP BY F.id;
```